# AWS EC2 Instances/volumes showing status in-use cannot start after stop of both volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 AWS EC2 Instances showing status 'in-use'.  I cannot start the instances after I had earlier stopped both instances.

I have a FREE tier account and don't have technical support available.

Fred Z.

Comment: Hi Fred, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: `in-use` is normally a status associated with an Amazon EBS volume rather than an Amazon EC2 instance. Are you sure you are looking in the "Instances" tab of the console?